# DiskCheck Plugin shows that total space available is 0

Tags: jenkins-plugins

The Jenkins DiskCheck plugin shows that the available workspace is 0. But the drive has several Gb of space available.
What could be wrong?

Jenkins: v2.88
DiskCheck Plugin: v0.3
Slave: Linux Ubuntu 14.03 w/ Java8

```
13:42:15 Disk space threshold is set to :1Gb
13:42:15 Checking disk space Now 
13:42:18 diskspace is 0
13:42:18 Total Disk space in workspace is 0
13:42:18 Total Disk Space Available is: 0Gb
13:42:18  Node Name: myhost
13:42:18 Running Prebuild steps
13:42:18 ERROR: Disk Space is too low please look into it before starting a     build
```